Excel VBA : Element not found ---> NoSuchElementError
I am trying to automate web browsing using Excel VBA, with Seleinum Web driver. I am in first step in navigating the website, and I stuck. I am not able to find the element for the username and password field. I tried to use findElementByID , findElementByXpath, findElementByName, findElementByClass , all these methods did not work.
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/AJrEVJq8.png)
Sub StartAms()
    bot.Get "https://ams-web.omanairports.co.om/#/"
    bot.Wait 5000
    bot.FindElementById ("username")
End Sub


Can you load this page in another browser? Attempting to navigate to the url on my side results in error connection timed out. A quick google search pointed me to https://apps.omanairports.co.om/ePortal/

Hi Charles, yes, I can load it in Edge browser.

try this url
https://ams-web.omanairports.co.om

it timeouts also
